# Algorithm for optimal combinations to cut

Tags: algorithm, optimization, language-agnostic

Input: I have a master length of 10m and I have products that need to be cut in 3m, 4m, 5m dimensions.

I tried writing an algorithm that will generate the following table for me (optimal lengths):

```
3m 4m 5m Waste
3  0  0  1
2  1  0  0
1  0  1  2
0  1  1  1
0  2  0  2
0  0  2  0
```

I understand how it works but I don't know how to **turn this into code.**

I need some pseudocode or help with this (am I supposed to use recursion)?

Comment: The algorithm to use for this is linear optimization. Here is a good starting point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming I would suspect that min(Waste) is good to go, but perhaps you just want all possible combinations, where 1*3m with waste 7 would be a perfect legal answer.

Comment: `I understand how it works` -- if that is true then you should already have a pseudocode.

Comment: @Tool Okay then, please write what your goals are. All combinations for different input sizes? Generate just that table that you already have?

Comment: Do you need to generate the table of all possible combinations?  I would imagine that would grow quickly for non-trivial input. Could you skip the table and just go for your ultimate goal, which I imagine would be to find the one optimal combination of cuts?

Comment: Not all possible, only the best combinations, that is 1 0 0 is invalid because you can still add other columns without crossing the 10 limit.

Comment: So all combinations such that the Waste is less than the minimum cut length?

Comment: is the order of the table important?

Comment: mbeckish; exactly. Order isn't important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a naive attempt.  Exhaustive search within known limits.

```
masterLength = 10

print "3m 4m 5m Waste"

for l3m = 0 to floor(masterLenth/3)
{
    for l4m = 0 to floor(masterLength/4)
    {
        for l5m = 0 to floor(masterLength/5)
        {
            usedLength = l3m*3 + l4m*4 + l5m*5
            waste = masterLength - usedLength
            if (waste<3 and waste>=0)
            {
                print l3m,l4m,l5m,waste
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[edit] Slight improvement, reducing search space.

```
print "3m 4m 5m Waste"

masterLength = 10
remaining = masterLength

for l3m = 0 to floor(remaining/3)
{
    remaining = remaining-l3m*3
    for l4m = 0 to floor(remaining/4)
    {
        remaining = remaining-l4m*4
        for l5m = 0 to floor(remaining/5)
        {
            waste = remaining - l5m*5
            if (waste<3 and waste>=0)
            {
                print l3m,l4m,l5m,waste
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can improve this by changing the loops to `for l4m = 0 to floor((masterLength-l3m*3)/4)` and `for l5m = 0 to floor((masterLength-l3m*3-l4m*4)/5)`

Comment: Also, `usedLength = l3m*3 + l3m*4 + l3m*5` should be `usedLength = l3m*3 + l4m*4 + l5m*5`